# mat-tree angular material custom

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

---

Home.component.html

---

```
    <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-icon class="type-icon" [attr.aria-label]="node.type + 'icon'">
      {{ node.type ==='file' ? 'description' : 'folder' }}
    </mat-icon>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-icon class="type-icon" [attr.aria-label]="node.type + 'icon'">
      {{ node.type ==='file' ? 'description' : 'folder' }}
    </mat-icon>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

---

Home.component.ts

---

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTreeFlatDataSource, MatTreeFlattener } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';
import { FlatTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
// import { files } from './example-data';

/** File node data with nested structure. */
export interface FileNode {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  children?: FileNode[];
}

/** Flat node with expandable and level information */
export interface TreeNode {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  level: number;
  expandable: boolean;
}

export const files = [
  {
    name: 'material2',
    type: 'folder',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'src',
        type: 'folder',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'cdk',
            children: [
              { name: 'package.json', type: 'file' },
              { name: 'BUILD.bazel', type: 'file' },
            ]
          },
          { name: 'lib', type: 'folder' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'angular',
    type: 'folder',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'packages',
        type: 'folder',
        children: [
          { name: '.travis.yml', type: 'file' },
          { name: 'firebase.json', type: 'file' }
        ]
      },
      { name: 'package.json', type: 'file' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'angularjs',
    type: 'folder',
    children: [
      { name: 'gulpfile.js', type: 'file' },
      { name: 'README.md', type: 'file' }
    ]
  }
];


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {

  /** The TreeControl controls the expand/collapse state of tree nodes.  */
  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<TreeNode>;

  /** The TreeFlattener is used to generate the flat list of items from hierarchical data. */
  treeFlattener: MatTreeFlattener<FileNode, TreeNode>;

  /** The MatTreeFlatDataSource connects the control and flattener to provide data. */
  dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<FileNode, TreeNode>;

  constructor() {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(
      this.transformer,
      this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable,
      this.getChildren);

    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TreeNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
    this.dataSource.data = files;
  }

  /** Transform the data to something the tree can read. */
  transformer(node: FileNode, level: number) {
    return {
      name: node.name,
      type: node.type,
      level: level,
      expandable: !!node.children
    };
  }

 /** Get the level of the node */
  getLevel(node: TreeNode) {
    return node.level;
  }

  /** Return whether the node is expanded or not. */
  isExpandable(node: TreeNode) {
    return node.expandable;
  };

  /** Get the children for the node. */
  getChildren(node: FileNode) {
    return observableOf(node.children);
  }

  /** Get whether the node has children or not. */
  hasChild(index: number, node: TreeNode){
    return node.expandable;
  }

}
```

---

ERROR in src/app/modules/home/home.component.ts(349,5): error TS2322: Type '({ name: string; type: string; children: { name: string; type: string; children: ({ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; })[]; }[]; } | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type 'FileNode[]'.
  Type '{ name: string; type: string; children: { name: string; type: string; children: ({ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; })[]; }[]; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'FileNode'.
    Type '{ name: string; type: string; children: { name: string; type: string; children: ({ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; })[]; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'FileNode'.
      Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
        Type '{ name: string; type: string; children: ({ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; })[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'FileNode[]'.
          Type '{ name: string; type: string; children: ({ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children?:undefined; })[]; }' is not assignable to type 'FileNode'.
            Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
              Type '({ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; })[]' is not assignable to type 'FileNode[]'.
                Type '{ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; } | { name: string; type: string; children?: undefined; }' is not assignable totype 'FileNode'.
                  Type '{ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'FileNode'.

### Property 'type' is optional in type '{ name: string; children: { name: string; type: string; }[]; type?: undefined; }' but required in type 'FileNode'.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to be specific about what your question. I vote to close this Question.